# Enable-SPFeature doesn't work, but activation via Site Settings does. Why?

Tags: 2010, deployment, feature-activation

I have a weird problem... I'm trying to deploy a sharepoint solution in production. This project works fine in the test environment, but in production trying to enable the feature returns this error:

```
Enable-SPFeature : Could not load file or assembly 'YYYYY, Version=1.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a7a65c9275aa3510' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:17
+ Enable-SPFeature <<<<  -Identity ApprovazioneCommesse_ApprovazioneCommesse -Url "https://ZZZ.XXXXXX.org/sites/KKK"
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...etEnableFeature:   SPCmdletEnableFeature) [Enable-SPFeature], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletEnableFeature
```

But I know the file is there.
The really weird thing is that I can enable the same feature via web (site settings>site collection features> Enable)

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar errors quite often in the past when code has been developed without taking into account that a PowerShell script doesn't provide a valid HTTP/SharePoint context.

Most likely your feature assembly contains code which calls `SPContext.Current`, e.g. `SPContext.Current.Web`, or `SPContext.Current.Site`, or similar functions which are not available if you don't have a SharePoint website context.

Same applies BTW if you want to read/write to the SharePoint WebApplication web.config file using the `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager` class.

Comment: I'll check if this is the case, still I can't understand why I would work in the test environment and not in production (both activated via PowerShell)

Comment: In this case make sure all the resources you use in your code are accessible on the production machine. Sounds like there's something blocked.